# How does the browser handle quotes (single, double) as the input to a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, escaping, quote

Imagine a user inputs the following into a form:

```
I'd like to "eat" something.
```

The phrase contains both a single `'` and two `"`'s. If I were to write this direcly as a JS string I'd have to escape the `'` to prevent my string from terminating early:

```
var phrase = 'I\'d like to "eat" something'
```

What is the behavior of the browser when a user (or potentially malicious actor) inputs a `'` or `"` into a form and saves it to a var? Will the characters be automatically escaped?

**EDIT *16/04/14***: Reworded the question.

Comment: Perhaps. Try. It. Out?

Comment: you only have to escape it when writing the string in a script file. For instance try console.log('I\'d like to "eat" something') in your favorite browser's console

Comment: @YoshuaWuyts Considering that you just typed all those characters into a form in order to type this question, and then posted it, obviously it is not catastrophic.

Comment: If you're writing in _HTML_, escape for _HTML_. If you're writing in _JavaScript_, escape for _JavaScript_. If you're writing in _SQL_, escape for _SQL_. If you're writing for many of these at once, escape them for the order they'll be interpreted. If you're just typing into a _control_ and there is no interpreting going on, there is no escaping required.

Comment: @Chris, I realize that. However I'm curious to how the browser handles saving input to a variable in light of possible XSS attacks.

Comment: @PaulS. Could you give an example of how to escape for JS? There's no built-in function to do that.

Comment: @YoshuaWuyts I don't understand; why would _JavaScript_ have a function to escape quotes for _JavaScript_? By then it would already be too late. Additionally, don't use the evil `eval` or variants thereof

Answer (score 1):

It runs whatever internal code is needed to display the typed data in the UI.

If you access the data via JS and the DOM, then it will give you a data structure (a string) with those characters represented in the data.

If you submit a form, it will encode the data (according to the encoding specified by the `enctype` attribute on the form element), and put it in an HTTP request.

---

You need to worry about escaping characters with special meaning when you write code because some characters *have* special meaning in code.

User input doesn't have special meaning unless you start treating it as code (e.g. by `eval`ing it, or mixing it with other code (such as SQL or HTML) and putting it somewhere where that code will be parsed (such as sending it to a database server or putting it in an HTTP response)).

Answer (score 0):

Inputting it as the user in the form is not a problem. It will be automatically encoded by the browser when it is send to the server. A problem would be to have have a default value in the HTML source code like this:

```
<input type="text" value="I&#39;d like to &quot;eat&quot; something"/>
```

Those values would have to be encoded for it to not break the HTML.

Comment: s/break HTML/introduce XSS

Comment: Yeah, having user generated content in generated pages is a huge risk. You have to be careful with it